# What is the probability of buying my friend shoes which she already owns?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

I would like to buy a pair of Nike shoes for my friend's birthday, but I am afraid of buying her shoes that she already owns. She is a shoe collector and she has about 70 pairs of Nike shoes. Let's assume the online Nike store has n Nike shoe options to buy.

After studying about the [balls and bins problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balls_into_bins_problem), I would like to calculate the probability that I buy her shoes, which she already owns. How can I do that? What variables do I need to know before calculating the probability?

Simple solutions are highly appreciated as I am new to probability concepts.

Comment: When selecting a pair, you have a $N$ pairs to choose from. Some of them your friend already has and some of them, she doesn't. Let's assume that the online catalogue consists of all possible Nike shoes (that is, there are no discontinued models that the friend might actually have purchased long time ago). Now, the question only goes: What percentage does your friend own from the catalogue? If she has 70 pairs, the answer should be just
$$
\frac{70}{N}
$$ This is now equal t the probability of choosing a pair that she already owns. I think it's that simple.

Comment: What Matti P commented.  Note that you are **guaranteed** (presumably) that your friend *bought without replacement*.  That is, she never bought any of the N pairs that she *already owned.*